# Information Needed regarding .Net and its application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have seen Books on ASP.Net, VB.Net, etc...
Is there any book on .NET itself? 
Can i take advantage of .NET using C++ or i need to know C#??
Please  dont mind my question if it sounds stupid, but please do help me out!

And please name a few good books for the following:

1. VB.net
2. .NET
3. ASP.NET
4. C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read wiki about **.NET Framework**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

and here's a book

[http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Microsoft-Framework-Programming-Pro-Developer/dp/0735614229](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735614229)

First of all start reading the wiki article to understand what's the **.NET Framework**, after decide what exactly you want to do with it.

Maybe you don't need to know all this language? Maybe you need just one of them? Depending on what type of application you need.

Is it a web site or windows application or windows service or something else?